# Why is my laptop getting hot using Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, lenovo, overheating

I switched from Win7 to Ubuntu and found that my laptop is getting too hot. (very hot). When I was using Win7, it was very nice, cool.

Why this is happening and how do I fix it.

details:

Lenovo G570; Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75579/very-hot-running-with-ubuntu

Comment: I changed the window manager for something lighter and more efficient like e17 or xfce, it works pretty nice on my old eeepc.
You can install another window manager and choose the one you want to use before loging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with overheating in 11.10. At least most of those are fixed in Precise (which will become 12.04). I had similar issues with all my computers on 11.10, but never since. (Never before 11.10 either).

If you really want to get into it, you can try upgrading your kernel. Or maybe you'll rather want to upgrade to 12.04 Beta 1 on the first of March. Of course, you could always download it now and try it in a memory stick  or something, just to confirm that all the issues have been resolved. They should.

Comment: Upgrading kernel.. well, how could I do that. I think my current kernel is v3 (not sure). To what version should I upgrade and how stable it is on other functionality

Comment: As upgrading kernel is very big deal, will that clearly fix this error ??

Comment: Upgrading the kernel isn't such a big deal, since there's no dependencies to worry about. But I would probably suggest just waiting a little while and upgrading to 12.04. It should fix it. This has never been an issue with Ubuntu before 11.10, and I haven't heard anyone complaining about it in Precise. 11.10 was a very special version in many ways. There were extremely large system changes in that version.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an Intel based system like my [Lenovo X220](http://natalian.org/archives/2011/11/10/Thinkpad_X220/) you could try appending `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1` to your boot command line, which works for me. YMMV

Comment: I even use Intel; its 2nd Gen i5; However, I thought to use Win7 until its fixed ..

Answer (score 0):

Try dimming the screen brightness.  I have an Acer laptop that will get hot if I try running more than email and a browser.  Tried everything written about temp problems except a bios update.  Last night I dimmed my screen brightness down to 60%, was able to burn DVD, watch full screen video, email and browser, and download a torrent.  Laptop was warm, but did not get hot.  Full screen video would do it in less than 5 minutes before.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my HP ProBook4530s (I have i5 and ATI Radeon graphic card).
You should try activate "ATI/ADM proprietary FGLRX graphics driver" (post-release updates in my case).

System Settings -> Additional Drivers

Answer (score 0):

Just might be because your laptop hasn't undergone a complete service. Just go to any laptop repair shop and give your laptop a good service... heat sync. fan gets out of order because of the garbage stuck inside the ventilator, resultantly it doesn't let the heat out of the laptop... So try this solution and enjoy...