# HP 4510s Probook Overheating

Tags: 12.04, overheating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very hot running with ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75579/very-hot-running-with-ubuntu)

I am having overheating problems with Ubuntu 12.04. Average temperature is approximately 70-74 °C and when Skype is turned on it goes nuts over 80 °C. Elipse refuses to open for some reason and of course everything is slower than it should be. I also had Linux Mint 11 installed and same thing happened. Strange thing is when running Windows, everything is okay and temperature is normal. Of course I have googled this issue and found some advices like install Jupiter which helped just a bit, installed additional drivers, opened laptop and cleaned it completely, disabled fan always on option from Bios. I have also switched from Unity to classic old look and still temperature is the same. Somehow I think it has something to do with the graphics card but I am all lost now. Any advices? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware problem.  Check that your computer is a little off the table, at least 1/4 inch.  Check to see if the built in fan turns freely.  Blow it out with canned air to keep it free from dust.

Andrew

Comment: Hello Andrew. Thanks for the answer! Fan is turning freely. I have cleaned the laptop yesterday and changed thermal paste. Moving it off the table will not help because the fan is to the left side and not below.