# Note book is getting very hot when using Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, overheating, acpi, toshiba-satellite

I have bought a Toshiba satellite Pro L850 note book. It already has preinstalled windows 7 professional. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now my note book have two Operating systems. The problem is, my note book is getting very hot only if i load Ubuntu. It is working fine with windows 7. Can any one tell why this is happening? And can anyone suggest a solution for this problem? I really want use Ubuntu in my laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75579/very-hot-running-with-ubuntu?rq=1)?

Comment: @penreturn-There is no a useful answer at that link.I Checked Bublebee project.But they are saying its for NVDIA VGA.But mine is Intel

Comment: It seems most of the  questions related to overheat are not solved.So we can get a conclusion that there is a problem in Ubuntu regarding Over heat.

Comment: @Thabo I can't reach that conclusion as I do not have heat problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specs of your laptop, but i will offer some information from my own Toshiba and Linux experiments:

I have a Toshiba Satellite L300D laptop that would over heat while running Ubuntu.  What worked for me was this:

Open a terminal and run:

```
$gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

find the line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

and add the command "acpi_osi=" after "quiet splash"

so the line will end up looking like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="

after words, in the terminal again:

```
$sudo update-grub
```

and restart your computer.

This left the brightness keys of my laptop not working, but the fan now comes on and off as it should and the computer doesn't overheat.

This may or may not be a solution that works with your computer, but it may be worth a try if you are still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for beginners...

I have a dual boot in my Laptop (windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04). After updating I found that I am facing a overheating problem in Ubuntu.

I think this is a problem is caused by the GPU. I have an ATI redon GPU. A software named xdiagnose is responsible for overheating, I think. Because after removing it my overheating problem is solved.

Follow this process and remove the xdiagnose software. Then restart...

1. **go to software centre**
2. **Select installed from the top**
3. **then select 1st one ( accessories )**
4. **find xdiagnose and remove it**

I know this is not best solution... but it helped me ...